# Why does first BeginInvoke fail, when second try succeeds? Message loop not responsive?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

I have an `EventHandler` on a custom `Control`, which is called from a background thread and invalidates the control. To do this, I use `Invoke` as follows:

```cpp
void Foo::handleProgressChanged(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ args)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &Foo::handleProgressChanged), sender, args);
        return;
    }

    this->UpdateProgress();
    this->Invalidate(true);
}
```

**Under some rare conditions the call to `Invoke` causes a deadlock** although the message loop should be pumping. The callstack of the main thread is:

```
ntdll.dll!770c5ca4()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
user32.dll!75e6073f() 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason = -1, int pvLoopData = 0) + 0x3c8 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.WinFormsAppContext}) + 0x177 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x18 bytes
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun() Line 768 + 0x9 bytes    Basic
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel() Line 1444  Basic
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String() commandLine = Nothing) Line 491 + 0x7 bytes    Basic
...
```

I tried to switch to `BeginInvoke`, but the passed delegate was never executed. I found a workaround that is far from optimal and that I regard as an evil hack: If I call `BeginInvoke` twice, the second call has the expected effect:

```cpp
void Foo::handleProgressChanged(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ args)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        IAsyncResult^ r = BeginInvoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &Foo::handleProgressChanged), sender, args);
        if (!r->AsyncWaitHandle->WaitOne(1000, false))
        {
            r = BeginInvoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &Foo::handleProgressChanged), sender, args);
        }
    }

    this->UpdateProgress();
    this->Invalidate(true);
}
```

I am not able to boil the code down to a small self-contained example but my specific question are:

- **Under which conditions can `Invoke` block the background thread, when
  the UI thread is idle?**
- **Why is the second call to `BeginInvoke` successful, while the first one is not?**

I'm using .NET Framework 2 and C++/CLI, however I suppose the problem is not language-specific.

**Edit:**

To make it clearer: the original approach works most of the time. The first events in a session are handled as expected. But later, especially when the events occur frequently, it runs into the deadlock.

Comment: have you tried to do exactly that in c#.  not only that this is impossible to read, but maybe there is some error that isn't obvious at a first glance...

Comment: @Daniel: No. It's a quiet complex project and porting it to C# is no option.

Comment: InvokeRequired is an anti-pattern, you know it should *always* be true when you make the call from a worker thread.  So use it as a diagnostic instead, throw an exception when it is false.  Which lets you catch problems with starting the thread too soon or not stopping it before the window is closed.  Starting it too soon can be the cause of the deadlock.

Comment: @Hans: The target control is visible on the Form, long before the background thread is started. So I believe the cause of the deadlock must be something else.

Comment: @Stephan I didn't trying to suggest that you should convert the whole project, just the invoke part...

Comment: @Daniel, I doubt that there would be any difference because both, C# as well as C++/CLI would compile to the same IL code. Aside from the better readability, is there any reason why you think it would work in C#?

Comment: @Stephan the problem of yours is the WTF-kind-of-problem, so I'm guessing that maybe there is an error that is introduced due to unreadability of c++/cli